# Compare two params in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have some trouble to understand how to make it.

I have one hidden input, where placed value, for example

```
<input type="hidden" value="62" name="id">
```

And I have 200 links

```
<a href="#" id="f62"></a>
<a href="#" id="f63"></a>
<a href="#" id="f64"></a>
```

I need to hide all these links, except the one where the `id` matches the value of the hidden field

```
$(function () {
    var fav = $('.ms2_form > input').val();
    var fav_id = $('.cart-info .add_fav').attr('id');

    $('.cart-info .add_fav').hide();
    $('.cart-info .remove').hide();

    // .........................here i dont know, how to write expression

    alert(fav);
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. Would the `.not()` selector work? `a:not(#f64)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a class to each link

```
<a href="#" id="f62" class="mylink"></a>
```

Then hide all with jQuery

```
$('.mylink').hide();
```

Then show only the one you want based on the val

```
$('#' + val).show();
```

Comment: that is assuming val would be "f62" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
var id = $('[name=id]').val();
$('a[id^=f]:not(#f' + id + ')').hide();
```